# This keyword when function is called from hyperlink

Tags: javascript, this

I have many links on my web page used like this:

```
<a href="javascript:Test.Test(this);">Testing</a>
```

With `this` keyword I was expecting to get HTML element owner of that function. But, it shows me `window` object instead. Why is that? How can I get (with code used above) HTML element, owner of that function?

On my web page, HTML structure is much more complex. Every hyperlink is inside some other element, so if `this` is showing current element, then it is easy to get parent element.

```js
var Test = function(){
  
  var Test = function(element){
    
    debugger;
    
  }
  
  return {
    Test: Test
  }
}();
```

```html
<div data-iuser_key='49499'>
<a href="javascript:Test.Test(this);">Testing</a>
</div>
```

Comment: That is impossible.  You should use event handlers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What did you expect? Your code was run inside `javascript:`, which has no reference to the target element. By default `this` refers to `window`.

Instead, use a proper click handler:

```
<a href="#" onclick="Test.Test(this)">
```

Comment: What does javascript mean in this case? Browser object model?

Comment: `javascript:` is a vendor specific prefix that was left from the old days. It is not part of any specification, but usually `this` is referred to `window`.

Comment: In your code I've removed href='#', because it causes page navigation to the top. Without that, everything works as expected and this is inside function referred as element holder of the function.

Comment: Technically you should be using `event.preventDefault` inside the handler, but for demonstration purposes I used `href="#"`.

Comment: I understand, I've read about event.preventDefault. But what is wrong if href is simpy omitted? (OK, I've added style="cursor:pointer" to keep css) I think it's much simpler, if only intention from the link click is to call the function.

Comment: It's just a good habit to have that. If you don't need the click effect, you might as well use a `span` or a `button`.